# Excel if day is equal to date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula

[image]

I'm trying to get if the day of the row (F6) matches the second day off (h4) do hours*2 if total hours is greater than 48 and 7 days worked or If matches the first day off (g4) do hours*1.5 if total hours is greater than 40.

Comment: that seems tough .. no weekdays off, 12 hour workdays, and lunch at 2 in the morning

Comment: lol, we have 8 hour days with 2 scheduled days off.  I just work a lot of OT and DBL =) anything over 8 a day is 1.5 and anything on the 7th day as long as I worked 48 is double

Comment: Hi there. How long you have been stuck is not relevant and that you need help is obvious, so we tend to try that kind of material out. Please do not add it back in - moderators tend to uphold these sorts of edits. They are not meant to annoy question askers - they are just for the purposes of making a question easier to read. Please ping me if you wish to insist, so I can flag for a mod - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare a date to a day name, you can use the `TEXT()` function to convert date value to date string of any format

```
=IF(TEXT(F6,"dddd")=H4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

If you want multiple conditions, use the `AND()` function

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(F6,"dddd")=H4,J14>48,K3>=7),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: what about throwing in an OR to that so if its h4 do that or if its G4 do that if not either do something else

Comment: @yourmom yes and OR could be useful. In you case because the outcome is different depending on the OR, I would suggest using two layered IF's: `IF(2nddaylogic,2*rate,IF(1stdayofflogic,1.5*rate,1*rate))`

Comment: thanks, i played with it and came up with

    =IF(AND(TEXT(F6,"dddd")=H4,J14>=48,N12="Yes"),F14*(G3*2),IF(AND(TEXT(F6,"dddd")=G4,J14>40),F14*(G3*1.5),G3*F14))

I used it in the pay cells but it works =) Maybe I'll be able to get it to seperate the double and OT hours now too =)